# Iterate over divs within a div and of particular type of css

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to iterate over the divs containted within a div and of a certain type of css class ?

So iterate over all the divs within this jSfiddle that are within the div 'outerDiv' and are of type css - 'testCss'

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div class="testCss">test1</div>
    <div class="testCss">test2</div>
    <div class="testCss">test3</div>
    <div class="testCss">test4</div>
    <div class="testCss2">ignoreThis</div>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ya9ww/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that you've been asking for?

```
$("#outerDiv div.testCss") ...
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ya9ww/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#outerDiv div.testCss]').each(function() {

});
```

Comment: that is one weird looking class selector ;)

Answer (score 0):

This well let you "iterate" over all the of the divs like you said in your question. This isn't a good way to set the color, but I just wanted to show the use of the `.each()`

```
$('#outerDiv .testCss').each(function(){
   $(this).css('color','red');
});​
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/Ya9ww/9/

Answer (score 0):

As all other guys - I'm suggesting you:

```
$('#outerDiv > div.testCss]').each(function() {

});
```

One thing I've got to tell - use ">" to make sure you're not iterating nested divs like:

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div class="testCss">
      <div class="testCss">IgnoreThis</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```